# How do I recieve an array of objects in c++ from a c# DLL call

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dllimport

I am using "mixed mode" c++ and calling functions that are in a c# dll over which I have no control. I have all calls working in a c# test exe but I cannot convert the call that returns an array over to the mixed mode c++.  I dont need to modify the array in c++, just read it.

I have 2 options working in c#, getting either to work in c++ would be enough.

This is the base c# exe call to get the array from the c# dll

```
CoefficientGroup[] G = Cfg.GetCoefficientGroups();
```

in my c++ I have tried many options with the ^ to no avail - it wont compile

```
CoefficientGroup^[] G = Cfg->GetCoefficientGroups(); etc etc
```

I also tried this method in c# which worked fine

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator eG = Cfg.GetCoefficientGroups().GetEnumerator();
while (eG.MoveNext())
{
      CoefficientGroup X = eG.Current as CoefficientGroup;
}
```

but in c++ I could find no way to do the "as" cast in c++ that would compile - like below

```
System::Collections::IEnumerator^ eG = Cfg->GetCoefficientGroups()->GetEnumerator();
while (eG->MoveNext())
{
    CoefficientGroup^ X = (CoefficientGroup)eG->Current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found one answer myself.  I missed the hat on this cast
    CoefficientGroup^ X = (CoefficientGroup^)eG->Current;
Still interested in an answer to array declaration though